# How can I break down this tree using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two columns I1, I2 (both indexes into another table) and form a tree.

```
I1  I2
1   3
4   6
2   5
3   7
6   9
8   11
```

from which I would like to pull out the list as:

```
Group Num
1      1
1      3
1      7
2      4
2      6
2      9    
3      8
3     11
4      2
4      5
```

Right now I use code which keeps searching for matches until the number of matches on a run is the same number of matches as the previous run. Is there a way to use TSQL to break down the list.

Comment: Is this a "how to do oracle connect by prior in sql server" question?

Comment: What sql server are you using?

Comment: How did you come up with the values on your expected result coming from your table?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question more. We are not able to see the other table you are referring to.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server

Comment: In fairness to the the OP - this is actually a pretty tricky problem to articulate. A down-vote isn't warranted IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I erased my previous answer; I now fully understand what you are trying to do. This solution will work if your "tree" is up to 3 levels deep. If you inserted the values (7, 20) we would need to add an additional LEFT JOIN and additional UNION ALL.

This could also be done more cleanly using a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but, if you are dealing with a fixed number of levels, this technique will perform better.

```
-- your table
use tempdb
go
if object_id('dbo.mytable') is not null drop table dbo.mytable;
create table dbo.mytable
(
  I1 int not null,
  I2 int not null,
    constraint pk_cl_mytable primary key clustered(I1,I2)
);
go
insert dbo.mytable values (1,3),(4,6),(2,5),(3,7),(6,9),(8,11);
go

-- solution
WITH flatten AS
(
  SELECT 
    L1 = t1.I1, 
    L2 = t1.I2,
    L3 = t2.I2
  FROM dbo.mytable t1
  LEFT JOIN dbo.mytable t2 ON t1.I2 = t2.I1
),
setGroups AS
(
  SELECT [group] = row_number() over (order by L1), * 
  FROM flatten
  WHERE L1 NOT IN (SELECT L2 FROM flatten)
)
SELECT [group], L1 FROM setGroups
UNION ALL 
SELECT [group], L2 FROM setGroups WHERE L2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT [group], L3 FROM setGroups WHERE L3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [group]; -- not required, including for presentation purposes
```

Results:

```
group                L1
-------------------- -----------
1                    1
1                    3
1                    7
2                    5
2                    2
3                    4
3                    6
3                    9
4                    11
4                    8
```

If required, you could include each node's level in the hierarchy by including a static lvl value to call out each node's level:

```
WITH flatten AS
(
  SELECT 
    L1 = t1.I1, 
    L2 = t1.I2,
    L3 = t2.I2
  FROM dbo.mytable t1
  LEFT JOIN dbo.mytable t2 ON t1.I2 = t2.I1
),
setGroups AS
(
  SELECT [group] = row_number() over (order by L1), * 
  FROM flatten
  WHERE L1 NOT IN (SELECT L2 FROM flatten)
)
SELECT [group], L1, lvl = 1 FROM setGroups
UNION ALL 
SELECT [group], L2, lvl = 2 FROM setGroups WHERE L2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT [group], L3, lvl = 3 FROM setGroups WHERE L3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [group], lvl; -- not required, including for presentation purposes
```

results:

```
group    L1  lvl 
-------- --- ----
1        1   1
1        3   2
1        7   3
2        2   1
2        5   2
3        4   1
3        6   2
3        9   3
4        8   1
4        11  2
```

Comment: Just tried your solution and it is excellent (it runs for a table with 100K+ entries in under 5 seconds vs 1 hour for my brute force solution.) Very nice. But I need a solution that goes at least 8 deep (currently I have 7 but in the future it could go deeper). How do I change it to keep going. If you can show me how to add one level I can add 'n' additional levels.